# LINQ to entities : cannot call a method

Tags: c#, linq, entity-framework

I'm aware there are alreay a lot of posts concerning this issue, but i can't seem to find a solution for this.

Here's my Ling to Entities query :

```
IEnumerable<Tblstamp> changes = (from c in userGSN.edb.Tblstamp
                                 where (c.Ts_Date >= userGSN.DateLastCheck && 
                                        TimeSpan.Parse(c.Ts_Time) >= userGSN.TimeLastCheck)
                                 orderby c.Ts_Id ascending
                                 select c);
```

I want to compare `c.Ts_time` to `userGSN.TimeLastCheck`, but for that I have to convert the `c.Ts_Time` to a timespan (it is a string, and comes from a database I can't modify, tried everything). I also can't do the converting before the query in an other variable since I can't access it outside of the query.

Obviously, I get an error for trying to use the TimeSpan.Parse method in my query, but I can't find any workaround to this. I have tried using LINQ to Object but since I am really not used to it I couldn't make the equivalent query that i have here.

I am aware of the problem, I'm just trying to find a workaround and need some help please !

EDIT : 
So I tried the `DateDiff` function as suggested :

```
IEnumerable<Tblstamp> changes = (from c in userGSN.edb.Tblstamp
                                             where (c.Ts_Date >= userGSN.DateLastCheck && SqlFunctions.DateDiff("second",userGSN.TimeLastCheck,c.Ts_Time).Value > 0 )
                                             orderby c.Ts_Id ascending
                                             select c
                                             );
```

but it gives me the same error : `"LINQ to Entities does not recognize the method 'System.Nullable`1[System.Int32] DateDiff(System.String, System.Nullable`1[System.TimeSpan], System.String)' method, and this method cannot be translated into a store expression."`

Even though it clearly says [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd466158(v=vs.110).aspx) "You cannot call this function directly. This function can only appear within a LINQ to Entities query.", which is exactly what I'm doing ?!

Comment: What error you get ?

Comment: The usual "LINQ to Entities does not recognize the method 'System.TimeSpan Parse(System.String)' method, and this method cannot be translated into a store expression."

Comment: You might get away with `SqlFunctions.DateDiff` https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd466158%28v=vs.110%29.aspx

Comment: Maybe the method EntityFunctions.DiffDays may help you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There's no clean way to do this, so you'll have to think outside the box. Try using [`SqlFunctions.DateDiff`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd466158%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) to perform the check. You'll need to adapt it for your usage, but:

```
SqlFunctions.DateDiff("second", c.Ts_Time, userGSN.TimeLastCheck.ToString()) > 0
```

There are [other methods](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.objects.sqlclient.sqlfunctions_methods%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) that you can use, if `DateDiff` is not suitable. See [`EntityFunctions`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.objects.entityfunctions%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) as well.

Depending on what you're using to query the data, you might want [`System.Data.Entity.SqlServer.SqlFunctions`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.entity.sqlserver.sqlfunctions%28v=vs.113%29.aspx) instead.

Comment: Thx very much, i'll try it and post the result

Comment: You're welcome. Although you'd be best to change that `string` to something more suitable.

Comment: System.Data.Entity.SqlServer.SqlFunctions  doesn't work either in same case

Answer (score 0):

Linq to Entities does not support all functions since the query has to be translated to SQL:

```
 from c in userGSN.edb.Tblstamp.AsEnumerable()  
 //now you are allready getting the data from the database
 //so be carefull with that because you will have bad performance
```

Answer (score 0):

Every code you write in LinQ to get data from database must convert to a valid T-SQL query with valid statements. Not all C# methods have a correspondance in T-SQL so whenever you use them in your code while fatching data you will get errors.

You should either do modifications on the SQL side or use C# spesific functions after fething data from database, while working with entities in memory, or use fıunstions which comply with SQL statements.

Comment: That's my point, i know SQL doesnt recognize this method, i'm looking for one that does the equivalent and is recognized by SQL !

Answer (score 0):

If you can't get EF to translate your query to SQL, maybe you could do it yourself? See [Writing SQL queries for entities](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/data/jj592907.aspx)